# Is it necessary to have a view file with every controller action

Tags: zend-framework, controller, action

Whenever I create a new action in the zend framework controller using the zf CLI tool it creates the corresponding view file. However, I don't need the view file for every action in the controller.

If I delete that view file manually will it affect my project.xml file or have any other effect on my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to.

Been a while since i worked with Zend Framework. But if memory serves me well, you have two options here.

1 - `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);`
   Which will stop the view being rendered

2- You can simply do what you need to do and call `exit()` in the end of the of your action.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: but my question was not about rendering the view. I know I can skip the rendering part. but do I need to keep that view or I can physically delete it from views as it will never get rendered. So why it will be there at first place ?

Comment: you can delete it if you don't need it. But you need to state that you don't wanna render it or exit before it does.

Comment: Cool. If you think either of the answers here helped you, you should mark as the answer. Time to improve your 50% answer rate, other people will stop answering your questions. Just an hint :P

Comment: lol !! I was trying to . but stackoverflow asked me to wait for 1 minute. !! :P

Answer (score 3):

If your action does not require a view then you can disable it:-

```
public function myactionAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();//to disable layout
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);//to disable view
}
```

If you want to disable the view/layout for the whole controller then you can put the lines above in the `init()` method of your controller like this:-

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();//to disable layout
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);//to disable view
}
```

Once you have done that you can safely delete the view files without affecting anything else.

More details are available in the [Action Controller manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html).